# Optimization and scalability of an annidate MySQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, query-optimization, scalability

I have this annidate query:

```
SELECT [U_ProdId], [U_CompDesc]
FROM [dbo].[@BE_CMPNTS]
WHERE [U_CompId] IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [U_CompId]
    FROM [dbo].[@BE_CHARS] Carat JOIN [dbo].[@BE_CHARVL] CarVal ON Carat.U_CharValueId = CarVal.Code
    WHERE CarVal.Name LIKE '%Manico%' 
) AND [U_CompId] IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [U_CompId]
    FROM [dbo].[@BE_CHARS] Carat JOIN [dbo].[@BE_CHARVL] CarVal ON Carat.U_CharValueId = CarVal.Code
    WHERE CarVal.Name LIKE '%Nero%'  
) AND [U_CompId] IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [U_CompId]
    FROM [dbo].[@BE_CHARS] Carat JOIN [dbo].[@BE_CHARVL] CarVal ON Carat.U_CharValueId = CarVal.Code
    WHERE CarVal.Name LIKE '%Pelle%'  
)
```

I would optimize, for a scalability purpose, this query.

If I have a little number of Carval.Name options, the annidate query is fast. But if I had more and more options to append to the query, I had a computational cost very high.

How can I optimize, if there's a way, this annidate query? I have to use some join? And how? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this as a start:

```
SELECT
      [U_ProdId]
    , [U_CompDesc]
FROM [dbo].[@BE_CMPNTS]
WHERE [U_CompId] IN (
            SELECT /* DISTINCT */ /* see notes on this below */
                  [U_CompId]
            FROM [dbo].[@BE_CHARS] Carat
                  JOIN [dbo].[@BE_CHARVL] CarVal
                              ON Carat.U_CharValueId = CarVal.Code
            WHERE CarVal.Name LIKE '%Manico%'
                  AND CarVal.Name LIKE '%Nero%'
                  AND CarVal.Name LIKE '%Pelle%'
      )
```

3 things I try to avoid

1, % ... %

double-ended wildcards stops the use of indexes. For those conditions being searched for there will be a table scan. (= slow)

2, IN ( subquery )

IN() is very convenient, perhaps too convenient many people will use them when not needed or wise. IN() is perfectly fine to use when the number of items inside those parentheses isn't huge, but once that subquery starts returning lots and lots of values it will get slower and slower. I dislike using IN() when the subquery's result is "unknown" or "potentially very large". Here it is unknown - so I don't like it.

They might all be OK in terms of scale I just cannot tell.

3, distinct

this is an expensive operation although against a single field this isn't so bad. However it isn't actually required in this query when being used inside an IN()

This is perfectly valid syntax for using an IN():

select * from abc where id IN(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)

While this looks like nonsense to a human the effort required to reduce that list to "distinct" can outweigh the benefits. If the scale of the subquery isn't too large then I would suggest removing the distinct. There is no golden rule here, it will depend on the scale of the subquery. It may be better to continue with distinct - or not.

---

You might be able replace the IN() with an inner join but I would not be so confident to say it will be better without knowing much more about the tables and data.

Comment: sorry you are right should be AND's, I will change the query. Regarding NEED for distinct I cannot agree, IN() does not require you to have a distinct list. It might be faster with distinct - in your case - but that does not make this always true.